# Using @client, @export directives with @skip one

Tags: graphql, react-apollo

I try to do something like this:

```
const ACTION_QUERY = gql`  
  query action($actionId: ID!, $isProofingOff: Boolean) {
    action(actionId: $actionId) {
      isProofingOff @client(always: true) @export(as: "isProofingOff")
      title
      approvalsCount @skip(if: $isProofingOff)
      checked
      deadline
    }
  }
```

But get error: 
`[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$isProofingOff" of required type "Boolean!" was not provided.`

Local `isProofingOff` resolver returns bool value.

But seems that `@skip` is executed before `isProofingOff` resolver and gets `undefined` instead of boolean value.

Is there any workaround to run local resolver before executing `@skip` directive?

Comment: There's a bit of a circularity to what you're trying to do. `action` and `approvalsCount` are remote fields. `isProofingOff` is a child field of `action`, so the remote query will need to run *before* `isProofingOff` can be resolved, but then you want the value of `isProofingOff` to be used in running the that same query (since it's passed to an argument on a directive on `approvalsCount`).

Comment: @DanielRearden according to docs - ```the @client fields is first stripped from the document, and the remaining query is sent over the network to the GraphQL API. After the query has been handled by the remote resolvers and the result is passed back to Apollo Client from the API, the @client parts of the original query are then run against any defined local resolvers, their results are merged with the network results``` - it's impossible to do. Thanks for answering!